How to Integrate Gupshup with WhatsApp for One-to-One and Group Messaging, and Send Messages Through a Website?
I'm currently working on integrating Gupshup with WhatsApp for various messaging purposes.
I'd like to achieve the following:
Send one-to-one messages to WhatsApp users.
Create a WhatsApp group and send messages to that group.
Send messages through my website to users, I have just their phone numbers.
I've already set up a Gupshup account and am using the sandbox environment for testing. Here's what I have so far:
Steps Taken:
Account Setup:
Created a Gupshup account.
Accessed the WhatsApp sandbox environment.
Obtained the sandbox phone number and API key.
and able to send messages through sandbox to my whatsapp by connecting the Opt-In QR Scanner
I'm not sure how to proceed with creating a WhatsApp group and sending messages to the group using Gupshup. Could anyone provide guidance or example code for this?
Question:
Creating Groups: How can I create a WhatsApp group via the Gupshup API and send messages to the group?
I am looking for WhatsApp integration for my e-learning site where, whenever a teacher creates a classroom, test, session, etc., all the students in that classroom receive a message on whatsapp.
Any detailed guidance or example code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance for your help!

We really want one question per post, please. Please review the [help] and in particular How to ask as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].
